# Combinations of vectors (1 x n) taken m at a time from a matrix (k x n)

Tags: r, combinations

I'm new on this forum. I work in R.

I have a `matrix (k x n)` and I have to considere all combinations of the rows `vectors (1 x n)` taken 2, 3, 4 at a time.

Example:

Consider a matrix `m = diag(c(rep(1, 3)))`,

I want the combinations of the three rows vectors `(1 x n)` taken 2 at a time:

```
first: (1,0,0) and (0,1,0)
second: (1,0,0) and (0,0,1)
third: (0,1,0) and (0,0,1)
```

In a second moment, for each couple, I need to compute the sum on the columns.
Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: First off, this is not a forum and treating it like one will result in, let's say, suboptimal results. I strongly suggest reading [ask] and [faq] for more information on how to use the site.

Comment: `combn` is probably the key, but please be as clear as possible on the output data structures you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m <- diag(c(rep(1, 3)))
tmp <- combn(nrow(m), 2)
array(t(m[tmp,]), c(ncol(m), 2, ncol(tmp))) 

#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1
#[3,]    0    0
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    0
#[3,]    0    1
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    1    0
#[3,]    0    1
```